# Lie algebras of upper central series of connected Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, nilpotent-groups

Let
\begin{equation*}
1=Z_0(G)\lhd Z_1(G)\lhd ...\lhd Z_{n-1}(G)\lhd Z_n(G)=G
\end{equation*}
be the upper central series of a connected nilpotent Lie group $G$, i.e. $Z_i(G)=\{g\in G:[g,G]\subset Z_{i-1}(G)\}$, $i=1,...,n$.

**Question:** Are the $Z_i(G)$ Lie groups? If so, do we have $\text{Lie}(Z_i(G))=\mathfrak{z}_i(\mathfrak{g})$, where
\begin{equation*}
0=\mathfrak{z}_0(\mathfrak{g})\lhd\mathfrak{z}_1(\mathfrak{g})\lhd...\lhd\mathfrak{z}_{n-1}(\mathfrak{g})\lhd\mathfrak{z}_n(\mathfrak{g})=\mathfrak{g}
\end{equation*}
is the upper central series of $\mathfrak{g}=\text{Lie}(G)$? Any references would be helpful!

My thoughts: I know that the analogous statement is true for the lower central series. Also, I was able to prove that if
\begin{equation*}
1=N_0\lhd N_1\lhd ...\lhd N_{n-1}\lhd N_n=G
\end{equation*}
is a central series for $G$, where the $N_i$ are Lie groups, then the corresponding Lie algebras form a central series for $\text{Lie}(G)$. When trying to prove the statement for the upper central series, I tried to use induction but I got stuck. My Ansatz would work out if $\text{Lie}(\varphi^{-1}(Z(G)))=\text{Lie}(\varphi)^{-1}(\mathfrak{z}(\mathfrak{g}))$, where $\varphi$ is a surjective Lie group homomorphism. However, I don't know how to prove this... (Edit: I'm also aware of the closed subgroup theorem, so to show that the $Z_i(G)$ are Lie groups, it would be enough to show that they are closed.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm aware that the centers correspond, i.e. that $\text{Lie}(Z(G))=\mathfrak{z}(\mathfrak{g})$. However, I don't see how this works for the "higher centers" of the upper central series.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That would be great! I checked the books by Knapp and Hilgert/Neeb, and it seems that the upper central series is not even mentioned.

Comment: For connected, simply connected nilpotent Lie groups, the terms of the lower (or upper) central series are just given as the image under $\exp$ of the corresponding Lie algebra central terms, and thus are closed - see [here](https://www.personal.psu.edu/zxw14/MATH597/Chapter1.pdf), page $25$. It seems that many authors prove this only for the lower central series.   Of course, it also works for the upper central series as well. I will have a look at Warner's book tomorrow.